# sum of squared error vs rms error , which one is better suited for prediction models and why?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, rms

Two measures of error between the actual observed data ti and the predicted data according to a model, y(xi,w), for data points xi and model parameters w: the sum-of-squared errors, and the RMS error. Give two basic reasons why the RMS error is intuitively a ‘better’ measure.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
Merely dumping a homework problem on us is outside the site charter.

Answer (score 1):

They are essentially measuring the same thing, but the scaling of the RMS error is probably more intuitive because it is both in the same units as the measurements themselves (not squared), and should be roughly independent of the number of error terms (i.e. does not increase as O(n) if there are n measurements).

Comment: Additionally, the RMS can act as a sort of "average size of error", and that along with the max and min error values can be very useful in a great many situations.